# Refresh Downloads list

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, downloading

I have Android 4.4.3 on a Nexus 5.
I connected the phone to a laptop, and there I deleted most of the files in the Downloads directory of the phone.
Nevertheless, these files still show up on the phone when I open Downloads (of course, when I try to open them, I get an error).

Is there a way to refresh the Downloads list?

Answer (score 1):

This is a correction for Akhil's answer. I have tried this on Android Lollipop and it works :

Settings > Apps > All > *Download Manager* (*NOT* Downloads) > Clear Data and Clear Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:
Go to
**`Settings->Apps->Downloads`**(`in All Tab`)**`->clear data and cache`**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that sounds like what I should do indeed. Unfortunately, for some reason I cannot clear data (the button is greyed out) nor the cache (the button isn't greyed out but clicking on it doesn't do anything). I also tried to clear all the cache on the phone (in Settings->Storage) but that didn't change anything either ):

Comment: try force close app and see whether data&cache clear button is enabled or not.

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not enable the button. Oh well, I guess I'll manually delete every "ghost" entry from the Downloads list as suggested by Dennis. I suppose my issue could be reported as a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Long press on one of the entries to bring up the select menu. Click on each one of the files and press the trash icon in the upper right corner. The entries will be removed from the list but the files will remain in the Download folder. Too bad there is no 'select all' button.